# How to host a website with database having server as my Laptop for free and which has a https link?

Tags: web, localhost

I want to host my website which has a node js server and uses sql from xampp. It works great on my laptop using localhost. I want to host it on internet for free from my laptop. I want a https link which can connect to my laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do this by using a module of nodejs called localtunnel. Suppose you choose a subdomain popeye assuming it is not taken before and port you are using for localhost is 3000 , then use following command .

```
$ npm install -g localtunnel
$ lt --port 3000 --subdomain popeye
```

Then whenever you go to link

http://popeye.localtunnel.me it will server from your computers localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Register domain name. Use a dynamic DNS provider to map your domain name to your current IP.

This can be more or less complex.

Consider some cheap VPS server. On the long run this may be easier and cheaper, than dealing with dynamic DNS.